# Перехват событий в slick slider, не работает event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, slick.js, slider-slick.js

Всем привет!

Имею https://codepen.io/iwan-klepalskij/pen/abaowzm 2 вложенных друг в друга slick слайдера, первый листает объявления недвижимости, а второй должен листать только список фото конкретного объявления.

Сейчас работает так что всегда происходит перелистывание только родительского slick slider (списка объявлений).
Пробую, остановить выполнение события, проверяя css класс у target родительского slick slider, но event.preventDefault() упорно не срабатывает.

```js
slick_parent.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("products__item-img")) {
    console.log('Меня вызвали на slick фото объявления, поэтому нужно остановить выполнение родительского slick и выполнить slick slider по фото');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: event.stopPropagation

Comment: Не срабатывает, выложил код https://codepen.io/iwan-klepalskij/pen/abaowzm